# PHP on Wordpress with Wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I tried to connect to a database which I already made by using phpmyAdmin, to store data that I took from a form. But when I add the Php code in the text editor of wordpress page, it shows the php code instead of execution.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't allow code execution within posts and pages. You'll need to use a plugin.

Comment: I tried, but not working... :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use Wordpress Plugin API. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API